# include standard c library on eclipse make file project

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded

I am working on embedded system which have hardware specific library. I am using eclipse make file project. In build/makefile the specific hardware files included but I want to include standard c library with my project how could i do that please give me a way out.

Comment: Does youe toolchain or embedded operating system provide a version of the standard C library for the embedded system?  Usually if it does and the toolchain knows about it, you would need a linker flag to include (or more likely exclude) the C library.  Header file includes, and other build system packaged libraries should be able to be referenced by relative paths or library names if the toolchain is well configured, if not you may need to set the -I and -L paths to an appropriate placed in the build system installation.

Comment: No my toolchain not provide the standard C support.can you give me a small example to include it in make file?? Is it INCFLAGS??

Comment: If your toolchain does not include a C library for your target, you are going to have to find/build one for the target system before you can include/link it.  But most toolchain ports do have one - you probably need to spend some time with the documentation for your toolchain.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: click project->properties->C/C++ general->Paths and symbols (see screenshot below).

[image]

Now select the language on the left panel (`GNU C` probably) and enter the include directories you need.